# ReactJs this.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I'm trying to change the value of a `this.state.id` with an `<input>` tag value, when I click on a `<a>` tag as follows:

```
 {this.state.json[1].map(i => (
    <tr>
        <td>{i.cin}</td>
        <td>{i.nom}</td>
        <td>{i.prenom}</td>
        <td>
             <a onClick={() => this.state.click(i.id)} >
                   <input value={i.id} hidden></input>
                   Create a New Folder
             </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
```

but the console says `this.setState is not a function`. This is my component:

```
    constructor(props)
{
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      json:JSON.parse(props.data),//data received from a laravel controller used to 
      implement the page.
      objet: '',
      id: '',
      click: function(id){
          var a = id;//a is an integer 
          alert('hitting waypoint 1');//clear hit
          this.setState({//error
          id: a,
          }).bind(this);
          alert('hitting waypoint 2');//not alerting
          alert("id = " + this.state.id)//not alerting
      }
    };
    this.onChangeValue = this.onChangeValue.bind(this);
    this.onSubmitButton = this.onSubmitButton.bind(this);     
}
```

Comment: `click` does not belong in state. There's already an answer explaining how to fix, so I'll just say: state is for values that change over time. Unless you're updating the click function for some reason based on your component state, it just shouldn't be there. Plus, binding it within the `state` object will make `this` refer to the state object, not the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the larger issue here is that you should probably not have this function within your component's `state`. If you declare it similar to your other handlers (`onChangeValue` and `onSubmitButton`) and bind like you did in the constructor, the function will probably work correctly.

If, however, you wish to keep the function inside `state`, changing it to an arrow function will probably solve the issue. Also, as a best practice, you should change the use of `var` to `let` or `const`.

Your improved function could look like this:

```
click: (id) => {
    const a = id;
    alert('hitting waypoint 1');
    this.setState({
        id: a,
    });
    alert('hitting waypoint 2');
    alert("id = " + this.state.id);
}
```

As an aside, `setState` is asynchronous, so the last alert (`this.state.id`) may not return what you think it will. If you want to use the new id directly after you set it, you should use the `const a` from earlier to guarantee that it has the correct value. Using state is (generally) better left to the `render` function.